# Setting UIImage transform affects UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, transform

My aim is to create an UIImage that scales automatically as I scroll in an UIScrollView. This works just fine but as soon as the scale of my image is set to something like .6 you aren't able to scroll in the UIScrollView anymore (even if you reset the scaling to 1 or 0.5 or/and reassign the content size of the scrollview). This is very strange because setting the scaling to 1, .75, .5 or .25 doesn't affect the scrollview (i. e. it works as it should). I'm using `transform` instead of setting the frame size because I want the image to be centered by the AutoLayout. Is there a better way of scaling an image without touching `frame`? And why does setting the scaling of an image affect a scrollview at all?

This is the code I'm using for resizing the image:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = sideScroller.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat scrollOffset = sideScroller.contentOffset.x;

    float fractionalPage = scrollOffset / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);

    [pageControl setCurrentPage:page];

    if (scrollOffset > pageWidth)
        scrollOffset = (pageWidth * 2) - scrollOffset;

    float logoSize = 1 - ((scrollOffset / pageWidth) / 2);

    logo.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(logoSize, logoSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but the content size of the content inside of the scroll view isn't changing because of the transform. Try scaling by frame instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Scaling by frame works (I've already tested it before) but automatic constraints are not working then. I just don't understand why scaling an image outside this scrollview has an effect on the scrollview itself. Is there maybe another way for scaling something with all the constraints working?

Comment: Perhaps a workaround is to also set the contentSize upon scroll.